# Как преодолеть ошибку при установке Ubuntu рядом с Windows 10: "Не удалось выполнить команду grub-install/dev/sda2"?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-10

Есть цель - поставить убунту рядом с Windows 10. До этого линукс никогда не устанавливал, а опыт использования был непродолжительным и не связанным с его технической частью.

В какой-то момент установки вылетает окно со словами: "Не удалось выполнить команду 'grub-install/dev/sda2. Это неисправимая ошибка.'":

[image: Не удалось выполнить команду 'grub-install/dev/sda2. Это неисправимая ошибка]

Потом 2 окна, что установка завершена, и что программа установки аварийно завершена. Потом ещё одно окно с заголовком: "Installation failed", и текстом: "The installer encountered  an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again".

При повторной установке всё то же.

Если кому-то внесёт ясность какая структура дисков моего ноутбука, то вот:

[image: структура дисков]

- Красным выделен тот раздел, куда я намерен установить убунту;
- Если я ничего не попутал, то: sda4 - диск C, sda7 - диск D, sda8 - то место, куда я хочу поставить убунту.

Да, я искал решения. Например, есть такой ответ: https://askubuntu.com/a/571582. Возможно, это решение, но я его даже с переводчиком не понял :( .

Если нужны ещё какие-то данные, то уточняйте, я сделаю апдейт вопроса.

**UPD1.** Попробовал установить grub не в sda2, а в sda - всё то же, прерывается на том же месте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение сводится к использованию утилиты **Boot repair**. Вот [побольше](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/boot_repair) информации о ней. А вот [инструкция](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fleF4qDtwDE), которая меня выручила.

Алгоритм решения приблизительно следующий:

1. После ошибки перезагружаете компьютер
2. Заново запускаете установочную флешку
3. Вместо установки выбираете попробовать Линукс
4. Устанавливаете Boot repair
5. Запускаете и выбираете Recommended repair (верхняя кнопка)